# What is the name for this class of rooted DAGs?

Tags: graph-theory, directed-graphs

Is there a name for the class of directed acyclic graphs where, for every node with more than one predecessor, none of the *direct* predecessors are in any of the others' ancestry? I.e. the most recent common ancestor of any pair of a node's direct predecessors is not either of the pair.

I have found the concepts of mangroves and polytrees, but do not understand very well whether they are applicable here. I believe polytrees are a more restrictive concept than what I am looking for, because I specifically do want to allow a node to have multiple "siblings" (from a common grandparent) as direct predecessors, just so long as it does not directly link to the grandparent or any of *its* ancestors.

I'm specifically interested in the case where there is a root but I don't expect that to make much difference to the above.

As an example, using this picture from Wikipedia [image]

This graph does not meet my criteria because the D node connects to B (or equivalently, C) and also A, which is B's predecessor. The node E is also triply disqualifying because it links to D and C, D's predecessor, but also links to both C and A, C's predecessor. It would still be disqualifying if the link C->E was removed because A is a predecessor of D. This would meet my criteria if the link from D to A was removed, and any single one of the links to E was retained and the rest removed. Additionally (although I'm less sure about this) , if we retain only the link D->E, there is no way to add another single node to the graph with more than one parent/predecessor without breaking the criteria above, because everything would be an ancestor of E.

Comment: It might be nice to draw a couple of examples of the kinds of graphs you do and don’t want to permit.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have added a diagram and some more concrete explanation of what I mean

Comment: I believe you can call that a [Hasse diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram), right? Or a "Hasse graph"?

Comment: Do you want a transitively reduced DAG?